# str_replace_all by position, applied over a vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, purrr

I have a data frame where each entry is some number of strings, separated by commas. I want a neat way to replace every element by position.

here's a toy version of the data

```
 library(tidyverse)

d1 <- tibble(
  r1 = c("lab1",
         "lab2,lab3",
         NA,
         "lab3,lab4"),
  r2 = c(NA,
         "lab1",
         "lab2",
         "lab2,lab3")
  )
```

So every `lab` element I want replacted by the corresponding `rep` element.

```
d1 %>% 
  modify_at(1:2,
        ~ str_replace_all(.,
                          c("lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4"),
                          c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3", "rep4")))
```

Returns

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
         r1        r2
      <chr>     <chr>
1      rep1      <NA>
2 rep2,lab3      lab1
3      <NA>      lab2
4 lab3,rep4 lab2,lab3
```

so I've only made a single replacement per cell in `r1`, whereas I need to replace them all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
  d1 %>% 
      modify_at(1:2,
                ~ stringr::str_replace_all(.,
                                           c("lab1" = "rep1",
                                             "lab2" = "rep2",
                                             "lab3" = "rep3",
                                             "lab4" = "rep4")))
```

To perform multiple replacements in each element of string, pass a named vector (c(pattern1 = replacement1)) to str_replace_all

Answer (score 3):

You could use `multigsub` from the `qdap` package:

```
library(qdap)

d1 %>% 
  modify_at(1:2,
            ~ multigsub(c("lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4"),
                        c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3", "rep4"),
                        .))
```

> ```
>          r1        r2
> 1      rep1      <NA>
> 2 rep2,rep3      rep1
> 3      <NA>      rep2
> 4 rep3,rep4 rep2,rep3
> ```

If your real use case just requires replacing `lab` with `rep`, regardless of the number that follows, you could also do:

```
map_df(d1, ~ gsub("lab", "rep", .x))
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `stringi`-package:

```
library(stringi)

patt <- c("lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4")
repl <- c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3", "rep4")

d1[] <- lapply(d1, stri_replace_all_fixed, patt, repl, vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

The result:

```
> d1
         r1        r2
1      rep1      <NA>
2 rep2,rep3      rep1
3      <NA>      rep2
4 rep3,rep4 rep2,rep3
```